# Can any adjective be used as comparative?

Tags: adjectives, comparatives

I was talking with my friends the other day about what is heathy to eat, I brought up the fact that something can be healthy if you compare it to something that is not healthy. You could say a doughnut is healthy if you compare it to bacon but you can say a doughnut is very unhealthy if you compare it to a salad. Likewise, I could say that I'm tall, but in comparison to my house I'm not very tall at all. Are all adjectives comparative?

Comment: Hi John, welcome to ELU. I don't think your question is a very good fit for our site, but you've given me pause for thought in selecting a reason to close it. I think the short answer for you is **Yes**. If you apply any adjective to something, by implication you're saying it *doesn't* have any qualities in direct conflict with that adjective. And *most* adjectives are relative to something - but that something varies according to context. A hot drink is **cold** compared to a hot sun, for example. Well, almost any sun, actually, even a cool one.

Comment: What about a binary state like pregnancy? Either you are pregnant or your are not, you can't be more pregnant than someone. Or death?

Comment: Why would people ask one thing in the title and forget it towards the end of the body?

Comment: @Sam good point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Many can't be, for a number of reasons. A brief summary from [here](http://www.durov.com/study/Grammar-1539.txt):

> With regard to the category of comparison English adjectives are classed into

- **Comparables** (qualitative adjectives, some of which have no degree of comparison):
- - those expressing the highest degree, e.g. *supreme, extreme*
- - those having the suffix *-ish*, e.g. *reddish, yellowish*
- - denoting incomparable qualities, e.g. *deaf, dead, lame*
- **Non-Comparables** (derived adjectives: *Crimean, wooden, mathematical*)

Comment: "We the People of the United States, in Order to form a more perfect Union ..."

Comment: Nice answer. "Unique" is an absolute,  "very unique" is mistaken and should be avoided.

Comment: @Concrete Gannet: Toad didn't think so: ‘Toad Hall,’ said the Toad proudly, ‘is an eligible self-contained gentleman's residence, very unique.’

Comment: This has come up before. “perfect” and “unique” both have comparable senses as well as the usual incomparable senses: “perfect” can mean “mature” and “unique” can mean “rare / unusual”.  (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unique)  You may argue that these senses are obsolete or non-standard, but in order to claim that “very unique” is grammatically wrong you must first demonstrate that the speaker is not using the comparable sense of “unique”.

Comment: Are these comparatives prohibited syntactically? (I don't think so). I don't think they are prohibited semantically either. Logically and literally, things like 'more extreme' certainly do show a lack of ...um... thought. But for all your examples I can think of very plausible comparatives. Even 'pregnant'.

Comment: Some physics textbooks are more mathematical than others!

Comment: Yes, one can almost always find some interpretation that makes use of the spectrum afforded by comparison of extent -- for instance, "a little bit pregnant" and "more pregnant than Jane" are understandable. That doesn't mean they're normal, it just means we're creative. And certainly any prohibitions are semantic, not syntactic.

Answer (score 2):

There's syntax and then there's semantics.

Syntactically, superlatives, like 'most interesting' or 'tallest', are adjectives that grammatically cannot  be used to from superlatives. That is

> *tallester or *'more tallest'

is not syntactically allowed. Also it doesn't make much sense; logically how can something be taller than the tallest?

For most other adjectives, one can form, according to the rules of English grammar, superlatives. But semantically there can be problems. There's the old chestnut

> a little pregnant,

because most saliently one is either pregnant or not. So semantically

> more pregnant

should be logically impossible. However, most words and concepts (outside of mathematics) allow range of application and vagueness and metaphor. One can be further along in a pregnancy, more American, deader than a door nail. So comparative formation is more productive than one would expect logically.